# Get list of files group by Date

Tags: bash, file, ls

I have a directory with files coming for every day. Now I want to zip those files group by dates. Is there anyway to group/list the files which landed in same date.

Suppose there are below files in a directory

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 anirban anirban    1598 Oct 14 07:19 hello.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 anirban anirban    1248 Oct 14 07:21 world.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 anirban anirban  659758 Oct 14 11:55 a
-rw-rw-r--. 1 anirban anirban    9121 Oct 18 07:37 b.csv
-rw-r--r--. 1 anirban anirban     196 Oct 20 08:46 go.xls
-rw-r--r--. 1 anirban anirban    1698 Oct 20 08:52 purge.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 anirban anirban   47838 Oct 21 08:05 code.java
-rw-rw-r--. 1 anirban anirban 9446406 Oct 24 05:51 cron
-rw-rw-r--. 1 anirban anirban  532570 Oct 24 05:57 my.txt
drwxrwsr-x. 2 anirban anirban      67 Oct 25 05:05 look_around.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 anirban anirban   44525 Oct 26 17:23 failed.log
```

So there are no way to group the files with any suffix/prefix, since all are unique. Now when I will run the command I am seeking I will get a set of lines like below based on group by dates.

```
[ [hello.txt world.txt a] [b.csv] [go.xls purge.sh] [code.java] ... ] and so on.
```

With that list I will loop through and make archive

```
tar -zvcf Oct_14.tar.gz hello.txt world.txt a
```

Comment: Will it help if you are able to place files on different directories based on their dates?

Comment: @SulavTimsina If you can give that code.. I can make it happen to zip those :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the GNU version of the `date` command, you can get the date of modification of a file with the `-r` flag, which can be very useful.
For example, given the file list in your question, `date +%b_%d -r hello.txt` will output `Oct_14`.

Using this, you could loop over the files, and build up tar files:

- If the tar file doesn't exist, create it with a single file
- If the tar file exists, add the file to it
- After the loop, zip the tar files

Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tarfiles=()

for file; do
    tarfile=$(date +%b_%d.tar -r "$file")
    if ! [ -f "$tarfile" ]; then
        tar cf "$tarfile" "$file"
        tarfiles+=("$tarfile")
    else
        tar uf "$tarfile" "$file"
    fi
done

for tarfile in "${tarfiles[@]}"; do
    gzip "$tarfile"
done
```

Pass the list of files you want to archive as command line parameters, for example if `/path/to/files` is the directory where you want to archive files (listed in your question), and you save this script in `~/bin/tar-by-dates.sh`, then you can use like this:

```
cd /path/to/files
~/bin/tar-by-dates.sh *
```

Comment: There is no error in the code at least when I am running nothing comes up in console. Tried with `set -x`, for some reason it is not entering in the for loop.

Comment: Pass the list of files you want to archive as command line parameters. I added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Write another script wrapped around this one, putting the necessary commands in it. If you need more detailed steps on how to read configuration from a file and use it in a cron job, I think that really belongs in another question.

Answer (score 0):

Create zero-seperated list of *(Month_Day.tar FILENAME*) pairs and use *xargs* to add each file to the corresponding archive:

```cs
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf "%Tb%Td.tar\0%f\0"|xargs -n 2 -0 tar uf
```